# angularJS cached data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have a service does update, add and delete. 
once update, add or, delete is called, the below code is called immediately to get the updated result.

If there are 10 items and I add one item, the alert increases 1 in my local environment, so it becomes 11.  But it stays 10 on the server when it should be 11. If I refresh the page then it updates to 11. Looks like it is cached. How to I change it to get it to load the correct result all the time?

```
    mySvc.list.promise.then(function(logonArray) {
        $scope.Logons = {data: angular.copy(logonArray)};
        alert($scope.Logons.data.length);
    });
```

Comment: Check the network calls in the browser and see what the server returns. It seems to be a server-side configuration...

Comment: I figured out the problem. a developer turned on cache:true in the http get call. What I needed to do is $cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(url); after every add/update/delete call.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a developer turned on cache:true in the http get call.

So first check if the cache is turned on.

You will need to remove the cache by doing this `$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove(url);` after every add/update/delete call.